# PHP Readfile, limit concurrent downloads per ip?

Tags: php, readfile

I've setup php to authorize download of file which works

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($_GET[l]) . "\"");
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($_GET[l]));
header("Connection: close");
ob_end_flush();
readfile($_GET[l]);
```

My problem now is that i would want to limit the amount of concurrent readfile downloads per ip, is there a way to do this? I am also looking for a way to limit the bandwidth of sendfile, i've tested using the built in apache module called "ratelimit" which works if apache is sending the file but not if i am using php.

Any ideas?

EDIT: Absolutely insecure, read comments below for tips on another method!

Comment: `readfile($_GET[l]);` is a huge security risk!

Comment: could you elaborate?

Comment: One could enter `?l=index.php` or worse and download your source code or configs etc. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_Local_File_Inclusion

Comment: wow, ok... will do a new approach...whats the best way to securing sending of files?

Comment: How I would do it is move the "downloads" out of the web-root, then have some code to enumerate the directory and store the information in a database, then when you want to serve them, use a dynamic id to reference them (base62[file_id, user_id]), check the user is allowed to access the file, then serve the file though php with fopen. this will then allow you to "rate" limit as you send the file to the user in chunks with a usleep in between. Have a look at how [FatFree](https://github.com/bcosca/fatfree/blob/e9aec879272c7474294c51c6c00802615afa32a6/lib/web.php#L130) does it.